# How is this npm switch fixing Windows path length issues

Tags: node.js, npm

On Windows NPM has issues due to its deep nesting of dependencies. In order to fix this a friend suggested the following command

`npm install <dep> -g --no-bin-link`

The man pages say about this command

`The --no-bin-links argument will prevent npm from creating symlinks for any binaries the package might contain."`

Could anyone explain, in plain language, what the impact this flag has on allowing dependencies to be installed that would usually causing deep path issues?

Comment: Here is the pull reqeust: https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/3090/files. Looks like it just doesn't bother linking at all.

Comment: @DavinTryon thanks for the link, I'm still unsure what that means. This is my first jump into non .net so for me I can't actually see what the end result of this command changed or how it stopped the path exceeding the Windows Limit :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could anyone explain, in plain language, what the impact this flag has on allowing dependencies to be installed that would usually causing deep path issues?

Sure.  Many packages published on `npm` can be used both as a command-line tool and programmatically.  For example the `jslint` package publishes both a command-line tool for linting files and an API that can be `require`d, so you can write code that uses `jslint`

The deep path issues usually become visible when creating the files that go into the `bin` directory, for command-line use.  The deep paths usually do not affect packages used programmatically with `require`.

So for "regular" dependencies of a package, it is usually harmless to omit the bin links, because those dependencies are consumed with `require`.

For "dev" dependencies or packages installed globally, it is usually necessary to keep the bin links, because those packages are more likely to be used as command-line tools.

Incidentally you should update to the latest `npm` if you haven't yet -- latest is 2.1.16 at this writing, and a guide for updating `npm` on windows is here: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

Comment: Does the update of npm have any relevance for the question? I am confused by the mention

Comment: Yes. Historically `node` distributions come out more slowly than `npm`, and there is often a substantial lag between `npm` being released and `node` incorporating a current npm.

Anybody using stock `npm` with node 0.10.x should upgrade.